# Titanium Alloy javascript execution

Tags: javascript, titanium-alloy

I'm approaching Titanium/Alloy for mobile app developement. I'd like to know if I can in some way run my Js code (Alloy models included) without compiling/deploying app to the emulator/device. Of course I'm talking about pure code, not yet related to UI. This would save a lot of time, for example during trials in dealing with a json server, data parsing, model filling, etc..

Is it possible and how, maybe via Node?
Thanks Max

Comment: Try live view in appcelerator studio. it will also help you to save your development time.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try something like https://jsfiddle.net/ to mess with generic JavaScript or http://tifiddle.com/ to play with the Titanium SDK.